# Ubuntu Studio 14.04.01 input method app missing in notification area

Tags: 14.04, system-tray, ubuntu-studio, notification-area, input-method

I just installed Ubuntu Studio 14.04.1 on a machine but I don't see the input method app in tray like in the normal ubuntu distro. How do I enable it? There is no such option to display it in the notification app like in the normal ubuntu in keyboard settings. I forgot how I enabled it on my other machine. Any ideas?

I am talking about this thing in the red circle. It is missing in Ubuntu Studio 14.04.1 with ubuntustudio desktop environment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is IBus running? `Settings Manager -> Other -> Keyboard Input Methods` should show you configuration window.